# Product not displaying on frontend joomla virtuemart

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart

I am new to Joomla, need to solve the problem. Please help.

Am using VirtueMart extension for managing products in my joomla site. I have added products in the back end, but they are not displaying on the front-end of the website. Here is the screenshot of the back end product section.

Am using Joomla! 2.5.6

I have set the "In stock" as 10 under "Product status"

[image]

Comment: What is your linktype? Maybe: "VirtueMart » Category Layout"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should absolutely update Joomla, you're 21 versions behind (current version is 2.5.27). It might not solve your problem, but it will absolutely make your Joomla safer. From your screenshot I can also tell you're using VirtueMart 2.0.10, the latest version is 2.6.10. Please update both. Just make sure to take a backup first, I recommend [Akeeba Backup](http://akeebabackup.com) (free or pro version).

As for your products not showing up: Please make sure you have created a menu item to display them, and set it up correctly. I can't see anything wrong with your configurations on your screenshot. Can you try this URL (replace `YOURSITE.COM` with your real domain name):

```
http://YOURSITE.COM/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=virtuemart
```

You should see your categories, a couple of recent products and others, depending on your settings.

Normally, you should create a menu item for VirtueMart in order to display products:

[image: VirtueMart Menu item selector]

Make sure filtering options are correctly set if your products still don't show up.

In addition, several modules are available that can display items from one or more categories, or based on date, or hits etc... (There are about 550 extensions available for VirtueMart in the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions)).